# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getUri()Lorg/eclipse/jetty/http/HttpURI

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, gwt, jetty

I have this exception when launching my application via eclipse plugin: "Run as" > "GWT Development Mode with jetty"

Environment:
- GWT SDK 2.8
- spring-boot 1.5.3.RELEASE
- jetty 9.4.4
- GWT Eclipse Plugin 3.0.0

**Stack trace**:

```
11:50:51,971 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[ROOT]
11:50:51,971 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
11:50:51,971 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@4c292313 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point

   Loading Java files in com.mycompany.fonems.webapp.Fonemswebapp.
   Ignored 1 unit with compilation errors in first pass.
Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to TRACE or DEBUG to see all errors.
   Module setup completed in 6335 ms

The code server is ready at http://127.0.0.1:9876/
Code server started in 6.611 s ms
Linking modules
   Bootstrap link for command-line module 'com.mycompany.fonems.webapp.Fonemswebapp'
      Linking module 'fonemswebapp'
         Invoking Linker Cross-Site-Iframe
            Ignoring the following script tags in the gwt.xml file
sc/skins/Simplicity/load_skin.js
sc/modules/ISC_Core.js
sc/modules/ISC_Foundation.js
sc/modules/ISC_Containers.js
sc/modules/ISC_Grids.js
sc/modules/ISC_Forms.js
sc/modules/ISC_RichTextEditor.js
sc/modules/ISC_Calendar.js
sc/modules/ISC_DataBinding.js
sc/skins/Enterprise/load_skin.js

[WARN] /isomorphic/skins/Enterprise/skin_styles.css
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: **org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getUri()Lorg/eclipse/jetty/http/HttpURI;
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$JettyRequestLogger.log(JettyLauncher.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.onCompleted(HttpChannel.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:435)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.Invocable.invokePreferred(Invocable.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.Invocable$InvocableExecutor.invoke(Invocable.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:672)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:590)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[WARN] ERROR dispatch failed
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getUri()Lorg/eclipse/jetty/http/HttpURI;
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$JettyRequestLogger.log(JettyLauncher.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.onCompleted(HttpChannel.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:435)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.Invocable.invokePreferred(Invocable.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.Invocable$InvocableExecutor.invoke(Invocable.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:672)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:590)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Suppressed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: s=COMPLETED i=false a=NOT_ASYNC
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannelState.onError(HttpChannelState.java:769)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handleException(HttpChannel.java:515)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannelOverHttp.handleException(HttpChannelOverHttp.java:463)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:451)
        ... 11 more
GET /recompile/fonemswebapp
   Job com.mycompany.fonems.webapp.Fonemswebapp_1_0
      starting job: com.mycompany.fonems.webapp.Fonemswebapp_1_0
      Compiling module com.mycompany.fonems.webapp.Fonemswebapp
         Ignored 1 unit with compilation errors in first pass.
Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to TRACE or DEBUG to see all errors.
         Unification traversed 598 fields and methods and 167 types. 0 are considered part of the current module and 5 had all of their fields and methods trave
rsed.
         Compiling 1 permutation
            Compiling permutation 0...
            Linking per-type JS with 0 new/changed types.
            Source Maps Enabled
         Compile of permutations succeeded
         Compilation succeeded -- 2,605s
      Linking into C:\Temp\gwt-codeserver-6157501051682194907.tmp\com.mycompany.fonems.webapp.Fonemswebapp\compile-2\war\fonemswebapp; Writing extras to C:\Temp\g
wt-codeserver-6157501051682194907.tmp\com.mycompany.fonems.webapp.Fonemswebapp\compile-2\extras\fonemswebapp
         Invoking Linker Cross-Site-Iframe
            Ignoring the following script tags in the gwt.xml file
sc/skins/Simplicity/load_skin.js
sc/modules/ISC_Core.js
sc/modules/ISC_Foundation.js
sc/modules/ISC_Containers.js
sc/modules/ISC_Grids.js
sc/modules/ISC_Forms.js
sc/modules/ISC_RichTextEditor.js
sc/modules/ISC_Calendar.js
sc/modules/ISC_DataBinding.js
sc/skins/Enterprise/load_skin.js

         Link succeeded
         Linking succeeded -- 2,776s
      6,914s total -- Compile completed
[WARN] /images/logoREC.jpg
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getUri()Lorg/eclipse/jetty/http/HttpURI;
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$JettyRequestLogger.log(JettyLauncher.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.onCompleted(HttpChannel.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:435)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.Invocable.invokePreferred(Invocable.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.Invocable$InvocableExecutor.invoke(Invocable.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:672)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:590)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <!-- POM file generated with GWT webAppCreator -->
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.natixis.fonems.webapp</groupId>
  <artifactId>Fonemswebapp</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>com.natixis.fonems.webapp.Fonemswebapp</name>

   <parent> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
   </parent>

  <properties>
    <!-- Setting maven.compiler.source to something different to 1.8
         needs that you configure the sourceLevel in gwt-maven-plugin since
         GWT compiler 2.8 requires 1.8 (see gwt-maven-plugin block below) -->
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>

    <!-- Don't let your Mac use a crazy non-standard encoding -->
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

    <smartgwt.version>3.1</smartgwt.version>

    <natixis.drh.version>2.0.0</natixis.drh.version>
    <natixis.drh.rmi.version>02.10.01</natixis.drh.rmi.version>

  </properties>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <!-- ensure all GWT deps use the same version (unless overridden) -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>

  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.natixis.fonems</groupId>
        <artifactId>fonems-fwk-server-common</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.104-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
                <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.natixis.fonems</groupId>
        <artifactId>fonems-refonte-dao</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.104-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
                <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
                <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>apache-jsp</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.smartgwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>smartgwt</artifactId>
        <version>${smartgwt.version}</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.smartgwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>smartgwt-skins</artifactId>
            <version>${smartgwt.version}</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>natixis.drh</groupId>
            <artifactId>newncauth</artifactId>
            <version>${natixis.drh.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>natixis.drh</groupId>
            <artifactId>natixis.droits-habilitations.rmi</artifactId>
            <version>${natixis.drh.rmi.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <!-- Output classes directly into the webapp, so that IDEs and "mvn process-classes" update them in DevMode -->
    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>

    <plugins>

      <!-- GWT Maven Plugin-->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>net.ltgt.gwt.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-rc-6</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>import-sources</goal>
              <goal>compile</goal>
              <goal>import-test-sources</goal>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <moduleName>com.natixis.fonems.webapp.Fonemswebapp</moduleName>
          <moduleShortName>Fonemswebapp</moduleShortName>
          <failOnError>true</failOnError>
          <!-- GWT compiler 2.8 requires 1.8, hence define sourceLevel here if you use
               a different source language for java compilation -->
          <sourceLevel>1.8</sourceLevel>
          <!-- Compiler configuration -->
          <compilerArgs>
            <!-- Ask GWT to create the Story of Your Compile (SOYC) (gwt:compile) -->
            <arg>-compileReport</arg>
            <arg>-XcompilerMetrics</arg>
          </compilerArgs>
          <!-- DevMode configuration -->
          <warDir>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</warDir>
          <classpathScope>compile+runtime</classpathScope>
          <!-- URL(s) that should be opened by DevMode (gwt:devmode). -->
          <startupUrls>
            <startupUrl>Fonemswebapp.html</startupUrl>
          </startupUrls>

<!--          <webappDirectory>${outputFolder}</webappDirectory> -->
        </configuration>

      </plugin>

      <!-- Skip normal test execution, we use gwt:test instead -->
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>
        <configuration>
          <skip>true</skip>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

**dependency tree**:

```
--- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:tree (default-cli) @ Fonemswebapp ---
com.mycompany.fonems.webapp:Fonemswebapp:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
+- com.mycompany.fonems:fonems-fwk-server-common:jar:0.0.104-SNAPSHOT:compile
|  +- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.9:compile
|  |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
|  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.3:compile
|  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
|  |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
|  +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.9.9:compile
|  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.1:compile
|  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
|  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
|  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.3.8.RELEASE:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.8.RELEASE:compile
|  |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.8.RELEASE:compile
|  |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.8.RELEASE:compile
|  +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.2.12:compile
|  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
|  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:18.0:compile
|  +- commons-betwixt:commons-betwixt:jar:0.8:compile
|  |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils-core:jar:1.7.0:compile
|  |  \- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:2.1:compile
|  +- net.sf.dozer:dozer:jar:5.4.0:compile
|  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
|  +- uk.org.lidalia:sysout-over-slf4j:jar:1.0.2:compile
|  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
|  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.11:compile
|     \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.11:compile
+- com.mycompany.fonems:fonems-refonte-dao:jar:0.0.104-SNAPSHOT:compile
|  +- com.zaxxer:HikariCP:jar:2.5.1:compile
|  +- org.lazyluke:log4jdbc-remix:jar:0.2.7:compile
|  +- com.mycompany.fonems:fonems-config:jar:0.0.104-SNAPSHOT:compile
|  +- com.mycompany.fonems:fonems-refonte-model:jar:0.0.104-SNAPSHOT:compile
|  |  +- org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics-runtime:jar:0.6.4:compile
|  |  +- openaccess:comFidessaInf:jar:3.0.1:compile
|  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:jar:1.5.3.RELEASE:compile
|  |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.5.3.RELEASE:compile
|  |  |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.5.3.RELEASE:compile
|  |  |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.5.3.RELEASE:compile
|  |  |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.5.3.RELEASE:compile
|  |  |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
|  |  |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
|  |  |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.17:runtime
|  |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.5.14:compile
|  |  |  \- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.3.5.Final:compile
|  |  |     \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.3:compile
|  |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:1.5.3.RELEASE:compile
|  |     +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:1.5.3.RELEASE:compile
|  |     |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.10:compile
|  |     +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:1.5.3.RELEASE:compile
|  |     +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.0.12.Final:compile
|  |     |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
|  |     |  \- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.0.Final:compile
|  |     +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.11.3.RELEASE:compile
|  |     |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.13.3.RELEASE:compile
|  |     |  \- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.3.8.RELEASE:compile
|  |     \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:4.3.8.RELEASE:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.8.RELEASE:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.3.8.RELEASE:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.3.8.RELEASE:compile
|  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.8.RELEASE:compile
|  +- org.hsqldb:hsqldb:jar:2.3.3:compile
|  +- commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.4:compile
|  |  \- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.6:compile
|  +- com.oracle:ojdbc7:jar:12.1.0.2:compile
|  \- de.jpdigital:hibernate5-ddl-maven-plugin:jar:1.0.0:compile
|     +- org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:3.3.9:compile
|     +- org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:3.3.9:compile
|     |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:3.3.9:compile
|     |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:3.3.9:compile
|     |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-settings-builder:jar:3.3.9:compile
|     |  |  \- org.apache.maven:maven-builder-support:jar:3.3.9:compile
|     |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:3.3.9:compile
|     |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-model-builder:jar:3.3.9:compile
|     |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-aether-provider:jar:3.3.9:compile
|     |  |  \- org.eclipse.aether:aether-spi:jar:1.0.2.v20150114:compile
|     |  +- org.eclipse.aether:aether-impl:jar:1.0.2.v20150114:compile
|     |  +- org.eclipse.aether:aether-api:jar:1.0.2.v20150114:compile
|     |  +- org.eclipse.aether:aether-util:jar:1.0.2.v20150114:compile
|     |  +- org.eclipse.sisu:org.eclipse.sisu.plexus:jar:0.3.2:compile
|     |  |  +- javax.enterprise:cdi-api:jar:1.0:compile
|     |  |  |  \- javax.annotation:jsr250-api:jar:1.0:compile
|     |  |  \- org.eclipse.sisu:org.eclipse.sisu.inject:jar:0.3.2:compile
|     |  +- com.google.inject:guice:jar:no_aop:4.0:compile
|     |  |  +- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
|     |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
|     |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.21:compile
|     |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-classworlds:jar:2.5.2:compile
|     |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-annotations:jar:1.6:compile
|     |  \- org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-sec-dispatcher:jar:1.3:compile
|     |     \- org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-cipher:jar:1.4:compile
|     +- org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:3.3.9:compile
|     +- org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:3.0-alpha-2:compile
|     |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-compat:jar:3.0-alpha-2:compile
|     |  |  \- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-provider-api:jar:1.0-beta-4:compile
|     |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-beta-3.0.5:compile
|     |  |  +- org.apache.xbean:xbean-reflect:jar:3.4:compile
|     |  |  |  +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.12:compile
|     |  |  |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging-api:jar:1.1:compile
|     |  |  \- com.google.code.google-collections:google-collect:jar:snapshot-20080530:compile
|     |  +- org.codehaus.woodstox:wstx-asl:jar:3.2.6:compile
|     |  |  \- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
|     |  +- org.sonatype.spice:model-builder:jar:1.3:compile
|     |  \- org.apache.maven:maven-project-builder:jar:3.0-alpha-2:compile
|     +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.24:compile
|     +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:5.0.12.Final:compile
|     |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.1.Final:compile
|     |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
|     |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.1.Final:compile
|     |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
|     |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.21.0-GA:compile
|     |  \- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jta_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.1:compile
|     +- org.hibernate:hibernate-envers:jar:5.0.12.Final:compile
|     +- org.reflections:reflections:jar:0.9.10:compile
|     |  \- com.google.code.findbugs:annotations:jar:2.0.1:compile
|     \- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.2:compile
+- com.google.gwt:gwt-servlet:jar:2.8.0:provided
+- com.google.gwt:gwt-user:jar:2.8.0:provided
|  +- com.google.jsinterop:jsinterop-annotations:jar:1.0.1:provided
|  +- com.google.jsinterop:jsinterop-annotations:jar:sources:1.0.1:provided
|  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:sources:1.0.0.GA:provided
|  +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:provided
|  \- org.w3c.css:sac:jar:1.3:provided
+- com.google.gwt:gwt-dev:jar:2.8.0:provided
|  +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.0:provided
|  +- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.3:provided
|  +- org.ow2.asm:asm-util:jar:5.0.3:provided
|  |  \- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:jar:5.0.3:provided
|  +- org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:jar:5.0.3:provided
|  +- colt:colt:jar:1.2.0:provided
|  +- ant:ant:jar:1.6.5:provided
|  +- com.ibm.icu:icu4j:jar:50.1.1:provided
|  +- tapestry:tapestry:jar:4.0.2:provided
|  +- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:jar:2.21:provided
|  |  +- xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.2:provided
|  |  |  \- xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.2:provided
|  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.3:provided
|  |  |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.6:provided
|  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.5.3:provided
|  |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.10:provided
|  |  +- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit-core-js:jar:2.17:provided
|  |  +- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:neko-htmlunit:jar:2.21:provided
|  |  +- net.sourceforge.cssparser:cssparser:jar:0.9.18:provided
|  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-client:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:provided
|  |     +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-client:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:provided
|  |     \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-common:jar:9.2.14.v20151106:provided
|  |        \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-api:jar:9.2.14.v20151106:provided
|  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:provided
|  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:provided
|  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:provided
|  |     \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:provided
|  |        \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:provided
|  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlets:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:provided
|  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:provided
|  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:provided
|  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:provided
|  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:provided
|  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-annotations:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:provided
|     +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-plus:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:provided
|     |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jndi:jar:9.2.14.v20151106:provided
|     \- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.2:provided
+- com.smartgwt:smartgwt:jar:3.1:compile
+- com.smartgwt:smartgwt-skins:jar:3.1:compile
+- mycompany.drh:newncauth:jar:2.0.0:compile
+- mycompany.drh:mycompany.droits-habilitations.rmi:jar:02.10.01:compile
+- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
|  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
\- org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:1.16.16:compile
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 5):

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` comes when we call a method which doesn’t exits in class.

You most likely have compiled a class against a different version of the class that is missing a method, than the one you are using when running it.

In your case something is calling `getUri()` method in `org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request` class which is no longer there in version 9. In version 9 it is called `getHttpURI()`.

http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/current/org/eclipse/jetty/server/Request.html

Comment: I understand what means this exception. But don't know why the old method getURI is called instead of the newer ??

Comment: Not 100% sure but might be called somewhere in at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$JettyRequestLogger.log(JettyLauncher.java:130).

Comment: I have already opened this class JettyLauncher: it just logs.  
 So, it is not the problem

Answer (score 2):

You have a mix of versions of Jetty.
You'll need to correct that to be on the same version of Jetty.

Dependencies on *9.2.14.v20151106*

```
org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-common:jar:9.2.14.v20151106:provided
org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-api:jar:9.2.14.v20151106:provided
org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jndi:jar:9.2.14.v20151106:provided
```

Dependencies on *9.4.4.v20170414*

```
org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-client:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:provided
org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-client:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:provided
org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:provided
org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:provided
org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:provided
org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:provided
org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:provided
org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlets:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:provided
org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:provided
org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:provided
org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:provided
org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:provided
org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-annotations:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:provided
org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-plus:jar:9.4.4.v20170414:provided
```

Comment: all these dependencies comes from the same artifact **com.google.gwt:gwt-dev:jar:2.8.0:provided**  
gwt-dev 2.8 is not stable?

Comment: I tested your solution but same error log 'java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:   org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getUri()Lorg/eclipse/jetty/http/HttpURI

Comment: GWT depends on 9.2.14, and Spring Boot in your parent POM forces many Jetty dependencies to 9.4.4 (through `dependencyManagement`). Split your client and server code into separate projects to avoid such conflicts.

Answer (score -1):

GWT has an embedded version of Jetty that mess everything up.

The GWT Super Dev Mode is not the right way to go when you have a complex environment.

Running the backend with Spring Boot (or whatever server you use) and the GWT Codeserver is the right thing do. 
At this point you can attach the codeserver and do GWT development.