# Getting Exception whenever I start Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, jetty

Whenever I run this command `java -jar jenkins.war --ajp13Port=-1 --httpPort=8080` it throws

First Jenkins started with daemon mode where it was restarting the process then I have tried to start it manually but getting the same error.

I even tried with older version of Jenkins as well but gettting the same error.

**Jenkins Version - 2.107.2**

```
Running from: /Applications/Jenkins/jenkins.war
webroot: $user.home/.jenkins
Apr 25, 2018 2:54:55 PM Main deleteWinstoneTempContents
WARNING: Failed to delete the temporary Winstone file /var/folders/60/r656jt5d01s0g2qtqdlycjbr0000gq/T/winstone/jenkins.war
Apr 25, 2018 2:54:55 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFO: Logging initialized @429ms
Apr 25, 2018 2:54:55 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Beginning extraction from war file
Apr 25, 2018 2:54:56 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog warn
WARNING: Empty contextPath
Apr 25, 2018 2:54:56 PM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Winstone shutdown successfully
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.updateBean(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Z)V
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.setHandler(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doSetHandler(ServletContextHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.relinkHandlers(ServletContextHandler.java:210)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.<init>(ServletContextHandler.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.<init>(WebAppContext.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.<init>(WebAppContext.java:221)
    at winstone.HostConfiguration$1.<init>(HostConfiguration.java:155)
    at winstone.HostConfiguration.create(HostConfiguration.java:155)
    at winstone.HostConfiguration.<init>(HostConfiguration.java:81)
    at winstone.HostGroup.initHost(HostGroup.java:66)
    at winstone.HostGroup.<init>(HostGroup.java:45)
    at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:145)
    at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:354)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at Main._main(Main.java:312)
    at Main.main(Main.java:136)
```

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43681727/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-org-eclipse-jetty-server-request-geturilorg-eclip. Could be of some help!

Comment: `--ajp13Port=-1` has no meaning.  What happens if you remove that argument?

Comment: If I simply run java -jar jenkins.war still giving me same error

Comment: A guess: you could have old jars from the prior run/execution/installation due to `WARNING: Failed to delete the temporary Winstone file /var/folders/60/r656jt5d01s0g2qtqdlycjbr0000gq/T/winstone/jenkins.war`?

Answer (score 0):

Check the dependency tree or open the war by extracting it and see that the particular method is available or not.

This may be the case when it is taking a wrong jar while building the war file from it.